# java.io.FileNotFoundException when running spark in cluster mode using YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark application that runs as expected on one node.

I am now using yarn to run this across multiple nodes. However, this is failing with a file not found exception. I first changed this file path from relative to absolute path but the error persisted. I then read [here](https://qnalist.com/questions/6408917/error-in-java-io-ioexception-no-input-paths-specified-in-job) that it may be necessary to prefix the path with `file://` in case the default is for HDFS. This file type in question is `json`.

Despite using the absolute path and prefixing with `file`, this error persists:

`16/11/10 10:19:56 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file://absolute/dir/file.json (No such file or directory)`

Why does this work correctly with one node but not in cluster mode with yarn?

Comment: is this file present in all the nodes?

Comment: No, it is present on one node. I had also tried the node address, so `file://me@server/dir/file.json`

Comment: You'd either need you file to be on a distributed fs like HDFS or on all worker nodes of your cluster under the same location.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash `/`.  Try:

```
file:///absolute/dir/file.json
```

The `file://` prefix here specifies the NFS file system, and you need to specify the absolute path from there beginning with a forward slash, requiring three forward slashes in total.